# Natural language with azure search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We are building a search engine wherein the user can type something like "I want the best xyz near me".
 
or some thing like "I want the top 3 people in xyz from abc(location)"
is this sort of arrangement supported by azure search.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Azure Search does not have an intent understanding system as you are asking for here.  For example, one intent you are looking for is (near me) which most likely means you want to take the geolocation of the user and then do an Azure Search query and perhaps weighting results that are close to this location.

To do this, one option is to [leverage LUIS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/language-understanding-intelligent-service/) (Azure - Language Understanding and Intent Service) where you can build out this intent system which are then mapped to Azure Search queries.

Liam

Comment: Thanks Liam, if we skip the "near me" part is it possible to build for something like "I want the top 3 people in xyz"

Comment: You can definitely do a query in cognitive search to do the actual query to retrieve this data, however simply sending the search text you specified will not do it.  You need to convert the search query you specified to a rest api call that uses geospatial filtering.  Basically, you would intercept the search query, determine if it is a "near me" query and convert the actual query performed into the format Cog Search expects.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Liam, Azure Search does not have an intent understanding system. Maybe you should implement the Logic in your Project and send a custom search query to your azure search instance.

There are many ways to design your queries to reach the desired behaviour. E.g.
you can set the "$top=#" parameter to 3 to retrieve the three results with the highest search score.

You can find more examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents

Answer (score 0):

You can also leverage other NLU tools like IBM's Watson NLU or the more affordable myNLU (https://mynlu.com). You will need to train their intents/entities, which should give you more control overall on how your solution works.